# Basic memory pool, alignment, thread safety

Tags: c, memory-management, thread-safety, memory-optimization

Mainly for practicing purposes, I'm trying to implement a simple, yet efficient memory pool. It's basically a linked list that is able to grow, with fixed sized members. Each node has a flag if it's free or not. I'm not sure if I'm doing it the right way, and especially confused about how to deal with alignment, and thread safety. I know the basic concept, just don't know how to implement in this case. Could you please help me how to improve my code? This is what I have now:

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include "mem_pool.h"


typedef struct block Block;

typedef struct block
{
    Block *next;
    void *ptr;
    bool free;
} Block;

struct mem_pool
{
    Block *head;
    void *memory;
    size_t memory_size;
    size_t memb_size;
};


#define get_ptr_and_increase(pool, size) pool->memory; pool->memory += size

#define add_block_size(pool) pool->memory_size += sizeof(Block) + pool->memb_size


static Block *new_block(MemoryPool *pool, bool is_free)
{
    Block *block = get_ptr_and_increase(pool, sizeof(Block));
    block->ptr = get_ptr_and_increase(pool, pool->memb_size);
    block->next = NULL;
    block->free = is_free;

    return block;
}

MemoryPool *pool_init(size_t memb_size)
{
    MemoryPool *pool = malloc(sizeof(MemoryPool));
    pool->memb_size = memb_size;
    pool->memory_size = 0;
    add_block_size(pool);
    pool->memory = malloc(pool->memory_size);
    pool->head = new_block(pool, true);

    return pool;
}

static Block *find_free(MemoryPool *pool)
{
    Block *current = pool->head;

    while (NULL != current && false == current->free) {
        current = current->next;
    }

    return current;
}

static void add_new_head(MemoryPool *pool)
{
    Block *tmp = pool->head;
    pool->head = new_block(pool, false);
    pool->head->next = tmp;
    add_block_size(pool);
    pool->memory = realloc(pool->memory, pool->memory_size);
}

void *pool_alloc(MemoryPool *pool)
{
    Block *free = find_free(pool);

    if (NULL != free) {
        return free->ptr;
    }
    add_new_head(pool);

    return pool->head->ptr;
}

void pool_free(MemoryPool *pool, void *block)
{
    Block *current = pool->head;

    while (current->ptr != block) {
        current = current->next;
    }

    current->free = true;
}

void pool_destroy(MemoryPool *pool)
{
    free(pool->memory - pool->memory_size);
    free(pool);
}
```

Comment: Does this code compile?

Comment: It did last time.

Answer (score 4):

#### Serious Bug

The moment you do this:

> ```
> pool->memory = realloc(pool->memory, pool->memory_size);
> ```

all the existing `head`, `next`, `ptr`, and `memory` pointers become invalid, since they were pointing into the memory that was just freed.  So essentially, your memory pool becomes useless after you expand it.

#### Unsafe macros

This macro:

> ```
> #define get_ptr_and_increase(pool, size) pool->memory; pool->memory += size
> ```

is unsafe for multiple reasons:

1. Arguments are not used inside parentheses, e.g. `(pool)`
2. The two statements could get split unexpectedly, such as in:

   ```
   if (condition)
       p = get_ptr_and_increase(pool, size);
   ```

I suggest creating a static inline function instead:

```
static inline void *get_ptr_and_increase(MemoryPool *pool, size_t size)
{
    void *ret = pool->memory;
    pool->memory += size;
    ret += size;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. What kind of techniques are there to implement a dynamically growing pool?

Comment: @Isty001 First, I would allocate large chunks instead of one element at a time.  Second, I would never free or realloc anything.  I would instead allocate a new large chunk when the first chunk got completely used up.